# AttributeError: 'TarFile' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Tags: python

I have searched the forum for this kind of error but couldn't find any so i am creating new thread for it. I am archiving one year old files with a below python script.

```
import os, time, tarfile
path = "/home/appins/.scripts/test/"
now = time.time()
yearago = now - 60*60*24*665
tar_file = "nas_archive_"+time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")+".tgz"
tar = tarfile.open(tar_file,"w:gz")
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        file = os.path.join(root,file)
        file = os.path.join(path, file)
        filecreation = os.path.getctime(file)
        if filecreation > yearago:
            tar.add(file)
            print file," is older that one year"
            os.remove(file)
```

It is working perfectly fine and i can view its content via. Now when I am trying to restore the archived files and getting the error AttributeError: 'TarFile' object has no attribute 'endswith'.

My restore script is simple:

```
import os, tarfile
archive_file = "nas_archive_07-31-2013.tgz"
tar = tarfile.open("nas_archive_07-31-2013.tgz")
tar.extractall(tar)
tar.close()
```

When i run this script i am getting below error :

```
python restore_archive.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "restore_archive.py", line 8, in ?
    tar.extractall(tar)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/tarfile.py", line 1541, in extractall
    self.extract(tarinfo, path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/tarfile.py", line 1578, in extract
    self._extract_member(tarinfo, os.path.join(path, tarinfo.name))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/posixpath.py", line 62, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'TarFile' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Is there anything which i am doing wrong in extraction? I am able to extract files using tar -xzvf command.

Answer (score 3):

The `extractall` method takes a path to extract to. I'm not sure why you're passing it the tar file object; you should be able to just leave the path argument out and have it default to the current directory.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. It was the one which was causing error.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [96]: help(tarfile.TarFile.extractall)

Help on function extractall in module tarfile:

extractall(self, path='.', members=None)
    Extract all members from the archive to the current working
    directory and set owner, modification time and permissions on
    directories afterwards. `path' specifies a different directory
    to extract to. `members' is optional and must be a subset of the
    list returned by getmembers().
(END)
```

So, `extractall` expects a path(`str` object) as first argument.

Comment: I removed tar file object from the extractall and it is working now.